# Converting a char array for use with isdigit()

Tags: c

I've been trying to write out code that takes input from the user, stores it into a `char` array, and then identifies the input as a positive or negative integer, a positive or negative decimal, or a character string. So far this is the code I have.

```
void input() { 
    char userInput[500];
    printf("Enter something: ");
    fgets(userInput, 500, stdin);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(userInput); i++) {
        if (isdigit(userInput) == 0) {
            printf("This is not a digit.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware that trying to use a `char` array with `isdigit()` will not work. I'm having issues figuring out how to get around this. I'm assuming it would be possible to run through the array and identify what the input is. And I assume there is a way to cast the `char` array into an `int` so `isdigit` would work, but I'm a bit stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: You do not test the entire array at once. You test each element in the array, with `isdigit((unsigned char) userInput[i])`.

Comment: "Any suggestions?" --> Posting the compiler warnings/errors is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple heuristics based on the character types to distinquish between integer, floating point, or string.

Introduce some new variables:

```
    int slash = -1;
    int digits = 0;
    int chars = 0;
    int decimals = 0;
    
    int isNumber = 0;
    int isNegative = 0;
    int isFloat = 0;
    int len;
```

Then your scanning code is this:

```
    len = strlen(userInput);
    for (int i = 0; i < len i++) {

        if (userInput[i] == '-') {
            slash = i;
        }
        else if (userInput[i] == '.') {
           decimals++;
        }
        else if  ((userInput[i] >= '0') && (userInput[i] <= '9')) {
           digits++;
        }
        else {
           chars++;
        }
    }
```

And then you can print the result as:

```
    // NOT A NUMBER if:
    //   a dash anywhere but index 0
    //   more than one decimal
    //   no digits
    //   anything else that isn't a digit
    isNumber = ( ((slash == -1) || (slash == 0)) &&
                 (decimals <= 1) &&
                 (digits > 0) &&
                 (chars == 0)
               );

     if (isNumber) {
         isFloat = (decimals == 1);
         isNegative = (slashPos == 0);
         printf("string contains a %s %s: %s\n", (isNegative ? "negative" : "positive"), (isFloat ? "double" : "integer"), userInput);
     }
     else {
         printf("string contains an ordinary string: %s\n", userInput);
     }
}
```

Comment: Aside from disallowing "+123", not too bad.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - That and leading/trailing whitespace.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the OP to complete.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some confusion between *digit*, which is a character between `'0'` and `'9'` and *integer* which is a number composed of such digits with an optional leading sign.

You can use `isdigit()` defined in `<ctype.h>` to check if a character is a *digit*, but testing if the string encodes a *number* is a different question.

Passing a `char` to `isdigit()` has undefined behavior is the `char` value is negative because `isdigit()` is only defined for a values of the type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`. To test if a `char` is a digit, you can write `isdigit((unsigned char) userInput[i])`.

To test if the string contains a number, you can use `strtol()`, and to test for a floating point value (which I assume you mean by *decimal*), you can use `strtod()`.

You can also use `sscanf()`, which is probably easier for a simple program.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void input() { 
    char userInput[500];
    printf("Enter something: ");
    if (fgets(userInput, sizeof(userInput), stdin)) {
        int n;
        double d;
        char c;
        /* try converting as an int,
           test if the conversion succeeds
           check that no trailing character is present.
           sscanf returns the number of successful conversions
         */
        if (sscanf(userInput, "%d %c", &n, &c) == 1) {
            printf("string contains an integer %d\n", n);
        } else
        if (sscanf(userInput, "%lf %c", &d, &c) == 1) {
            printf("string contains a double %g\n", d);
        } else {
            printf("string is an ordinary string: %s\n", userInput);
        }
    }
}
```

Note however that the above tests will accept leading and trailing whitespace and may invoke undefined behavior if the number cannot be represented in the target types.

Comment: When I tried to implement your code for a test I got this:

warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float*’, but argument 3 has type ‘double*’ [-Wformat=]
   if (sscanf(user_input, "%f %c", &d, &c) == 1) {

Comment: @ExaltedCaricature: OOPS! the correct format is `%lf`. sorry for this mistake. Kudos to you for using `-Wall` to detect silly mistakes like this :)